# How to initialize a mongoDB with TestContainers-go

Tags: testcontainers

I want to use TestContainers-go to setup a mongoDB,basically the following code works, however, I want to set mongo DB port, and user and password during initialziation. How to achieve it?

```
    // Start MongoDB container
    mongodbContainer, err := mongodb.RunContainer(ctx,
        testcontainers.WithImage("mongo:6"),
    )
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
```

Comment: In the next release of testcontaines-go it will be possible to customize the user and password for the mongodb module: https://golang.testcontainers.org/modules/mongodb/#withusername